# how to scrollto without animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

So I use the excellent plugin from [lions-mark](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/) that allows scrolling to any position a breeze. I use this mainly to keep the user at his current scroll location when the page refreshes (don't ask, mine is a legacy gaming site with auto-refresh in some instances)

So I store current scroll position into localstorage on `window.onBeforeUnload` and use that value to scroll to previous location after pageload.

`$('content-grid').scrollTo(offsetBeforeReload);`

This works, however I want to "jump" to that position without the animated scroll. I do not want to use anchors, since I already have this scrollTo code that works just fine, all I want to do is get rid of the scrollTo animation and made it look as if the page is 'anchored' to that location.

Any suggestions/solutions are very much appreciated!

Comment: Seems like browser keeps the position itself. Why do you need to scroll manually?

Comment: the accepted answer should be the one with the reference to `mounted()` by Dexter Legaspi

Answer (score 18):

Here's what I needed:

`window.scrollTo({ top:50, left:0, behavior: "instant"})`

Comment: I had to add a setTimeout with a 250ms delay before this would work

Answer (score 8):

the way i was able achieve this (in my case: to suppress scrolling animation to top while transitioning to a new view via [Vue Router](https://next.router.vuejs.org):

```js
  mounted() {
    document.documentElement.style.scrollBehavior = 'auto';
    setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), 5);
    setTimeout(() => document.documentElement.style.scrollBehavior = 'smooth', 5);
  }
```

this allows you to change the `style` property of the `html` node...switching from `scroll` to `auto` to stop it and then back to `scroll` once scrolling is done.  the `setTimeout()` is actually important otherwise the switch to `auto` won't actually take into effect.

note that this works even when you have set `html` set initially to smooth scrolling in your css:

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

i tried this on Chrome and Firefox on MacOS (Big Sur) and they seem to work.

this should also work without having to use Vue.js.

Comment: this should be the correct answer

Comment: Thanks, apparently the function window.scrollTo, even if passed the configuration behaviour:'auto' still does a scrolling, it's broken

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `duration` option to `0` which should scroll to the element instantaneously.

```
$('content-grid').scrollTo(offsetBeforeReload, {duration:0});
```

Here is the demo from the lions-mark website updated to use a zero duration: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeppc2z2/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo). This will jump directly to the position with no animations.

```
var xPosition = 0;
var yPosition = 1000;
window.scrollTo(xPosition, yPosition);
```

Comment: What about browser support?

Comment: @Qwertiy All major browsers support it after IE8.

Comment: @Qwertiy Yup, that's what that means. IE8 technically supports it but it's a bit quirky with how it handles units.

Comment: CSS property `scroll-behavior: smooth` will introduce a scroll animation/smoothness regardless.

Comment: this is not entirely correct.  as @undefined said, `scroll-behavior: smooth` will animate the scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementByID('your-element').scrollIntoView({behavior: "instant"});`

Works like a charm!

Comment: Why does this work? It's not mentioned in the spec but it seems that Chrome at least has implemented this with no documentation.

Comment: `instant` is not part of spec…there is an ongoing (albeit old) discussion about this: https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/1449

Comment: doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

`window.scrollTo(xPosition, yPosition)` works natively in all major browsers.

If you want to use jQuery, try the following:

```
$('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0, }, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'instant' })