# Using scrollTo without the scrolling animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Is there a way to 'jump' to the top of the page with a scrolling animation when a button is pressed?
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727664/how-to-scrollto-without-animation)'s solution doesn't work for me (there is a scrolling animation).

I've tried the following:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0 ,{duration:0});
window.location.hash = '#siteTop';
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
window.location.href ='#'
```

But they all have animations. Can anyone help (no jquery pls)?

Comment: `window.scrollTo` by default does not have scrolling animation. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) shows that the option `{ behavior: 'smooth' }` has to be passed to `scrollTo` for it to animate. --- Please provide a runnable [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: You might want to use : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop / https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft instead ?

Comment: yep scrollTo doesn't have animation by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible 
  <strong>when the user starts to scroll the page</strong>.</div>

<script>
//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```